# How to target SharePoint 2003 with a VS 2008 work environment

Tags: sharepoint, vsewss, wss-2.0

Currently I have a .NET setup that many workings devs have (VS 2008, SQL SRVR 2008, etc). However, the current client requires webparts to be built on a SharePoint 2003 (it is gov't, so they don't upgrade before doing MASSIVE testing).

I have not developed on SharePoint 2003 and understand that I can only directly create create webparts targeting this platform from VS 2003. Is there any way to create webparts targeted for SharePoint 2003 within VS 2008 (extensions maybe)?

Comment: It seems unlikely, since wss 2.0 used .NET 1.1. There is no support for .NET 1.1 in VS2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not with extensions, you would just have to do the old way (but in 2003 [Smart Part](http://www.u2u.be/res/SmartPart.aspx) works, so you have a user control as the container and a easier life). Just reference the 2003 assemblies and test with a custom pre-build event that copies the user controls to the deploy folder (be inetpub's or the /11/TEMPLATES/LAYOUTS) and a custom post-build event that updates the assembly in GAC or BIN folder for your site. That would give you a Ctrl+Shift+B automatic local deploy and Ctrl+Alt+P to attach to any running w3wp processes to debug.